# is this function in .NET safe to be shared?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, shared

I am writing a class, which will be used to POST data to twitter. Can someone clarify if this function is safe to be shared? Still find it difficult to grasp when a function is not safe to be shared., unfortunately..!

It will be returning back a basic dictionary, which I will then potentially add other parameters to after I have retrieved the basic signature.

```
Private Shared Function createbasesignature() As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
    Dim timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Dim oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()

    Return New SortedDictionary(Of String, String) From { _
{"oauth_consumer_key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("twitter_consumer_key")}, _
{"oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce}, _
 {"oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"}, _
     {"oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp}, _
{"oauth_version", "1.0"} _
}
  End Function
```

Comment: You are asking about thread safety, right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: It probably isn't about threading but about the *Shared* keyword in VB.NET.  Then again, hard to imagine there's an introductory book about VB.NET programming that doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine.  You're only accessing local variables and newly created objects (plus `DateTime.Now` but that's safe).  So no other thread would have any way to corrupt the data you're working with.